# How to split a sorted list by element length

Tags: python, list, sorting, split

I have a list of lists and it is sorted by the length of the children lists. e.g.

```
[[str], [str1, str2], [str1, str2], [str1, str2, str3], [str1, str2, str3],...]
```

I would like to split this list into sublists that only contain the children with the same length.
e.g.

```
[[[str], [str], [str]],  [[str1, str2], [str1, str2], [str1, str2]], ...]
```

I was wondering if there is a more efficient approach than mine below with hopefully a little less code.

```
child_list = []
new_list = []
old_list = [['e3510000'], ['e2512001'], ['e3510000'], ['e92d4010'],
            ['e3a0b000', 'e3a0e000'], ['e92d4030', 'e59f5054'],
            ['e59f3038', 'e3530000'], ['e1a0c00d', 'e92dd800']]

# length of child
length = 1
for idx, i in enumerate(old_list):
    if idx == len(old_list)-1:
        child_list.append(i)
        new_list.append(child_list.copy())
    elif length == len(i):
        child_list.append(i)
    elif length < len(i):
        new_list.append(child_list.copy())
        del child_list[:]
        child_list.append(i)
        length = len(i)
```

Output:

```
[[['e3510000'], ['e2512001'], ['e3510000'], ['e92d4010']],
 [['e3a0b000', 'e3a0e000'], ['e92d4030', 'e59f5054'], 
  ['e59f3038', 'e3530000'], ['e1a0c00d', 'e92dd800']]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) in order to group the lists in `old` by length. Note that if the original lists are already ordered according to their length as in your example, sorting here is not necessary.

```
from itertools import groupby
[list(v) for k,v in groupby(sorted(old_list, key=len), key=len)]
```

**Output**

```
[[['e3510000'], ['e2512001'], ['e3510000'], ['e92d4010']],
 [['e3a0b000', 'e3a0e000'],
  ['e92d4030', 'e59f5054'],
  ['e59f3038', 'e3530000'],
  ['e1a0c00d', 'e92dd800']]]
```

Comment: Thanks a million for the help! Great how this can be solved using a one-liner with the help of itertools.

Answer (score 2):

[groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is probably the most intuitive in this case, however, you can solve the problem differently using a dictionary datastructure:

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = [["str"], ["str1", "str2"], ["str1", "str2"], ["str1", "str2", "str3"], ["str1", "str2", "str3"]]
dct = defaultdict(list)
for el in data:
    dct[len(el)].append(el)

print(dct.values())
```

Out:

```
[[['str']],
 [['str1', 'str2'], ['str1', 'str2']],
 [['str1', 'str2', 'str3'], ['str1', 'str2', 'str3']]]
```

---

**Benchmark results:** Using the dictionary based solution is faster:

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import defaultdict

data = [["str"], ["str1", "str2"], ["str1", "str2"], ["str1", "str2", "str3"], ["str1", "str2", "str3"]]

def solve_with_groupby(data):
     return [list(v) for k,v in groupby(sorted(data, key=len), key=len)]

def solve_with_dict(data):
    dct = defaultdict(list)
    for el in data:
        dct[len(el)].append(el)
    return dct.values()
```

result:

```
In [10]: timeit solve_with_groupby(data)
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.75 µs per loop

In [11]: timeit solve_with_dict(data)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.56 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> l = [[1]*i for i in range(1, 5) for _ in range(3)]
>>> l
[[1], [1], [1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
>>> result = [list(g) for _, g in groupby(l, key=len)]
>>> result
[[[1], [1], [1]], [[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1]], [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]]
```

Alternatively if they are not ordered, you can use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> import random
>>> random.shuffle(l)
>>> l
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1], [1], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1], [1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for e in l:
...     d[len(e)].append(e)
... 
>>> result = list(d.values())
>>> result
[[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]], [[1], [1], [1]], [[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1]]]
```